# Vite - esbuildx.x.x is not compate with vite

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

##### Issue

I created a React JS project using vite when starting the server today ran into this error after an update

`X [ERROR] [plugin vite:dep-pre-bundle] Detected inconsistent metadata for the path "node_modules/react/index.js" when it was imported here:`

I am using vite version 2.9.1

Details of the Issue

```
  vite v2.9.1 dev server running at:

  > Local: http://localhost:3000/
  > Network: use `--host` to expose

  ready in 234ms.

X [ERROR] [plugin vite:dep-pre-bundle] Detected inconsistent metadata for the path "node_modules/react/index.js" when it was imported here:

    node_modules/react/cjs/react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:16:20:
      16 │ var React = require('react');
         ╵                     ~~~~~~~

  The original metadata for that path comes from when it was imported here:

    dep:react:1:23:
      1 │ export default require("./node_modules/react/index.js");
        ╵                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  The difference in metadata is displayed below:
  
   {
  -  "pluginName": null,
  +  "pluginName": "vite:dep-pre-bundle",
   }
```

#### System Info

```
System:
    OS: macOS 12.2.1
    CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7600 CPU @ 3.50GHz
    Memory: 426.07 MB / 16.00 GB
    Shell: 5.8 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 17.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.17 - ~/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin/yarn
    npm: 8.5.5 - /usr/local/bin/npm
  Browsers:
    Chrome: 100.0.4896.75
    Edge: 100.0.1185.39
    Safari: 15.3
  npmPackages:
    @vitejs/plugin-vue: ^2.3.0 => 2.3.1 
    vite: 2.9.1 => 2.9.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is about 'esbuild'.

https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/7683

you can fix it, just run

```js
yarn update esbuild // or npm update esbuild
```